# Managing dependencies on c# Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm starting to make some tests with Unit Tests (not TDD, just writing some tests at this moment) using Visual Studio and a strange questions came in my mind after a error explore into my Test Project.

First of all, I created a Web Api 2 project, created my Model, Controllers and other stuff. I've separated my repository, configured dependency injection and the project was fully functional.

After that, I created my Unit Test project, add a reference to the previous Web Api project, created a mock for my repository, instantiate my controller, passed the mock as constructor injection, called the method and asserted the result. The code was functional but when I compile, it complains about the can't find the ApiController from System.Web.Http.

The tries were:

- The first thing I've tried was, searching for the dependency in "Add Reference" context menu. I added but the version was different, so was not working.
- The second thing worked, but was very ugly.  Again entered in "Add Reference" context menu, browsed the directory from Web Api project and choosen the bin folder and selected all dlls. That worked, but was terrible, because once I version that test, will be broken because was referencing a path probably not available on the checkout computer.
- The third try was copy the package.json from the Web Api project and paste on the Unit Test project and run on the NuGet console "Update-Packages -Reinstall". The third option worked, but I don't know if is the correct way to do that.

**TL;DR;**

How do you guys reference all DLLs dependencies on Unit Test project?

**Edited:**

The error I got from the compiler is:

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Web.Http.ApiController' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.   C:\Users\fgadotti\Documents\Prototype\WeWorkout\WeWorkout\AnotherTest\UnitTest1.cs  13  13  AnotherTest
```

When I create a fresh Web Api project I have all this dependencies by default:
[Dependencies from a fresh Web Api project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKwSn.png)

And when I create a fresh new Unit Test project I only have the first two dependencies of the following image, the third dependency is from my Web Api project: 
[Dependencies from a Unit Test project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UFaC.png)

So, all the dependencies from Web Api project I have to manually reference in the Unit Test project to unit tests work properly or there are some smarter ways to do that?

Comment: When ever you do a nuget install click on your solution and hit manage nuget packages for this solution then always make sure you install for both the Web project and Test project

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the bottom line question. "How"? Well by choosing "Add Reference..." in Visual Studio, or using NuGet if you're talking about packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to see if there's smarter alternatives, but yes, typically what I do is just add the correct dependencies *manually* to the Test project.

Note that for NuGet you can easily manage the packages *at the solution level* and make sure they're added to both projects.

I've not ever felt the need (your projects need as few as possible dependencies anyways), but if you want a manual yet slightly more efficient way would be to open up both `csproj` files and synch the references that way.

Comment: The problem was that all my initial dependencies was created when I started a new Web Api project. I don't have any additional dependency to install through NuGet, because when the project was created all necessary DLLs were already there.

Comment: Then you'll need to add them manually with "Add Reference...", or resort to editing the csproj files, AFAIK.